# node.js express middlewares migrate to AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, session, express, lambda

I am trying to figure out a way that I can implement the session serverlessly on amazon web service lambda. Apparently I can not use "app.use" any more.

For example in my express app I have the following middleware sitting in app.use:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "testing credentials",
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie  : {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false
    }
}));
```

so in lambda, should I write the following instead? Because this will be trigged each time when the request come in.

```
session({
    secret: "testing credentials",
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie  : {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false
    }
});
```